# parsing in ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, session

I have this `Hash`:

```
cookie = {"fbs_138415639544444"=>["\"access_token=138415639544444|5c682220fa7ebccafd97ec58-503523340|9HHx3z7GzOBPdk444wtt&expires=0
&secret=64aa8b3327eafbfd22ba070b&session_key=5c682220fa7dsfdsafas3523340
&sig=4a494b851ff43d3a58dfa8757b702dfe&uid=503523340\""], 
"_play_session"=>["fdasdfasdf"]}
```

I need to get the substring from right after `access_token=` to right before `&expires`. The problem is that the number in the key `fbs_138415639544444` changes every time, just the part `fbs_` remains constant.

Any idea how to only get:

```
"138415639544444|5c682220fa7ebccafd97ec58-503523340|9HHx3z7GzOBPdk444wtt"
```

Comment: What is up with the extra quoting around the value for the first key?  Seems odd that it is `"\"access....\""`

Answer (score 2):

This is a common task when decoding parameters and queries in HTML URLs. Here's a little method to break down the parameters into a hash. From there it's easy to get the value you want:

```
def get_params_hash(params)
  Hash[ *params.split('&').map{ |q| q.split('=') }.flatten ]
end

p get_params_hash(cookie['fbs_138415639544444'].first)['"access_token']

# >> "138415639544444|5c682220fa7ebccafd97ec58-503523340|9HHx3z7GzOBPdk444wtt"
```

In Ruby 1.9+, hashes retain their insertion order, so if the hash always has the value you want as its first entry, you can use

```
cookie.keys.first #=> "fbs_138415639544444"
```

otherwise use:

```
cookie.keys.select{ |k| k[/^fbs_/] }.first #=> "fbs_138415639544444"
```

Answer (score 1):

I never code in ruby, but this sounds like a typical task for **split** function.
you just need to split this

> "\"access_token=138415639544444|5c682220fa7ebccafd97ec58-503523340|9HHx3z7GzOBPdk444wtt&expires=0
>   &secret=64aa8b3327eafbfd22ba070b&session_key=5c682220fa7dsfdsafas3523340
>   &sig=4a494b851ff43d3a58dfa8757b702dfe&uid=503523340\""

by **&** symbol. The first element of result array will be:

> "\"access_token=138415639544444|5c682220fa7ebccafd97ec58-503523340|9HHx3z7GzOBPdk444wtt"

and after split it by **=**, and the second element of result array should be:

> 138415639544444|5c682220fa7ebccafd97ec58-503523340|9HHx3z7GzOBPdk444wtt

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the `access_key` part, then a regex is probably easiest.

```
cookie["fbs_138415639544444"][0] =~ /access_token\=([-\w\d\|]*)&/
access_key = $1
```

Here the `access_key` is in the first capture group and you can get it with `$1`.

A better option if you'll need other parts of the string (say the `session_key`), would probably be to use a couple `split`s and parse the string into it's own hash.

Edit: Just realized you need the key too.

```
key = cookie.each_key.find { |k| k.start_with? "fbs_" }
```

Then you can use `key` to get the value.

Comment: It's a special global variable for dealing with regex matches (I think ruby got it from perl). Any variable of the form `$n` where `n` is a number holds values from the last regex match performed. `$0` holds the entire matched pattern `$1` is the first capture group `$2` is the second, etc. So, above everything matched by `([-\w\d\|]*)` got shoved into $1.

Answer (score 1):

Since the key changes, the first step is to get right key:

```
key = cookie.keys.select {|k| k =~ /^fbs_/}.first
```

This matches them if they begin with the text "fbs_".  The first match is returned.

Next you can get the other value by a few (ugly) splits:

```
cookie[key].first.split('=')[1].split('&').first
```

Using a regex might be a bit cleaner, but it depends on what the valid characters are in that string.

Answer (score 1):

Regexs are brittle so I wouldn't use those when the reality is you are parsing query string params in the end so use the CGI lib:

```
> require 'cgi'
=> true 
> cookie = {"fbs_138415639544444"=>["\"access_token=138415639544444|5c682220fa7ebccafd97ec58-503523340|9HHx3z7GzOBPdk444wtt&expires=0&secret=64aa8b3327eafbfd22ba070b&session_key=5c682220fa7dsfdsafas3523340&sig=4a494b851ff43d3a58dfa8757b702dfe&uid=503523340\""], "_play_session"=>["fdasdfasdf"]}
> CGI.parse(cookie.select {|k,v| k =~ /^fbs_/}.first[1][0])["\"access_token"][0]
=> "138415639544444|5c682220fa7ebccafd97ec58-503523340|9HHx3z7GzOBPdk444wtt"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved the problem...

```
  access_token_key = cookies.keys.find{|item| item.starts_with?('fbs_') }
  token = cookies[access_token_key].first
  access_token = token.split("&").find{|item| item.include?('access_token') }
  fb_access_token = access_token.split("=").find{|item| !item.include?('access_token') }
```