# how to access hash inside a string

Tags: ruby

I'm reading a CSV file. It contains a column as

```
{"doctype"=>"birthrecord", "records"=>[{"pagenum"=>"5", "recordId"=>"7", "tagGroups"=>[{"data"=>{"first"=>"given_name", "given_name"=>"Severiano ", "surname"=>"Bustamante"}}]}]}
```

The header of this columns is Output. When I do row["Output"] its returning sting of hash as

```
"{"doctype"=>"birthrecord", "records"=>[{"pagenum"=>"5", "recordId"=>"7", "tagGroups"=>[{"data"=>{"first"=>"given_name", "given_name"=>"Severiano ", "surname"=>"Bustamante"}}]}]}"
```

How can I access the hash like normal hash?

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: I know if I say `eval`, I'm going to get stoned to death (for a good reason), but... how desperate are you and how much do you trust the source?

Comment: possible duplicate of [parsing in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608211/parsing-in-ruby)

Comment: @JanDvorak, is it right way to use eval there? it works but...

Comment: Most likely not. The link I've posted looks relevant, though. Where is your string coming from?

Comment: There appear to be a few viable options outlined in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667630/how-do-i-convert-a-string-object-into-a-hash-object

Comment: We need to see your code and a sample of your input data. The "column" isn't CSV format, and instead appears to be a hash definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset looks almost like `JSON` except `=>` is used in place of `:`, so replacing them you can now adequately parse it like a `JSON` object

```
JSON.parse('{"doctype"=>"birthrecord", "records"=>[{"pagenum"=>"5", "recordId"=>"7", "tagGroups"=>[{"data"=>{"first"=>"given_name", "given_name"=>"Severiano ", "surname"=>"Bustamante"}}]}]}'.gsub("=>", ":"))["records"][0]["tagGroups"][0]["data"]
#=> {"first"=>"given_name", "given_name"=>"Severiano ", "surname"=>"Bustamante"}
```

Comment: The OP needs to clarify the input and show where the data displayed is coming from. It's not a CSV formatted record or field.